# Rails 4 + Capistrano 3 : fatal: Could not read from remote repository while deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, deployment, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I am getting following error while deploying Rails 4 application using Capistrano 3

```
INFO [87512eb8] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/magnificent/git-ssh.sh as deploy@104.236.6.180
DEBUG [87512eb8] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/magnificent/git-ssh.sh
INFO [87512eb8] Finished in 0.444 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1ec94dd1] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent.git as deploy@104.236.6.180
DEBUG [1ec94dd1] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/magnificent/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent.git )
DEBUG [1ec94dd1]    ERROR: Repository not found.
DEBUG [1ec94dd1]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [1ec94dd1]    
DEBUG [1ec94dd1]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [1ec94dd1]    and the repository exists.
```

Here is capistrano configuration.

**config/deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'magnificent'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent.git'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/magnificent'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
set :branch, 'develop' #set/ :branch,`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

**production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production
server 'xx.xx.xx.xx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.2'
```

I also copied /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub of remote server to github deploy keys.

**UPDATE**
I confirm that I am able to access remote repo and also  `GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/magnificent/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent.git` command works on remote server.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### Current Solution

Lately I use different solution. Before `cap production deploy` I run following commands.

1. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
2. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

#### Previous Solution

I am able to fix this issue by replacing

```
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent.git'
```

with

```
set :repo_url, 'https://my_github_username:my_github_password@github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/magnificent'
```

**Note** if your password contains special characters then thet should be url encoded. You can quickly encode using `URI::encode` in irb.

With other deployments using Capistrano 2, I never need to supply github credentials.

Can anybody please tell why should I have to specify git username/password in `repo_url`?

There is one more solution in the [upcase forum post](https://forum.upcase.com/t/capistrano-cannot-read-from-remote-repository/3009/6) which also worked.

Comment: I would not have implemented the original solution, but your update certainly helped me resolve my issue.

Comment: it works, but this sucks, its really bad security to commit this into git

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. Turns out I had loaded the wrong SSH key and it interfered with the deployment. Solved it by removing the wrong loaded ssh key like so:

`ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/wrong-ssh-key`

and then running the Capistrano deployment again.

Comment: which ssh key is the right one? My one or the one of the deploy user? Which deploy user? The local one or the one on the remote machine?

Answer (score 3):

This could also happen if you are deploying to the server for the first time, and the git server is not in the known host list of your deployment server.

so, logging into the remote server and then doing a git request to the repository will cause the git server to be added to the known host list.

like so:

```
git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:your_gitbucket_user_id/your_repo.git master

The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojabwzha.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

you should confirm to connect.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Now try deploying using the capistrano task.

```
cap production deploy
```

Comment: still getting "permission denied"

Comment: ... all right, fixed it, needed to prefix repo url with "git@" (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem(ubuntu). ssh-agent should be on. You can add it to startup applications.

Comment: yes that what works as well. Lately I started using `ssh-agent` before deploying. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

go to server box get id_rsa.pub and add it to keys on github

Answer (score 0):

One common mistake is that you might need to add the **public key of the server** to the access keys list of the repo. I always forget this and add the public keys of my local environment which never worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of a typo in the user/repo path (dash instead of underscore). Triple-check the path!

```bash
git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:your_gitbucket_user_id/your_repo.git master
# ---------------------------------------------------------^
# => fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:your_gitbucket_user_id/your-repo.git master
# ---------------------------------------------------------^
# => Success!
```